# Compute Shader - gl_GlobalInvocationID and local_size

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

While trying to implement a naive Compute Shader that assigns affecting lights to a cluster, i have encountered an unexpected(well for a noob like me) behavior:

I invoke this shader with glDispatchCompute(32, 32, 32); and it supposed to write a [light counter + 8 indices] for each invocation into "indices" buffer. But while debugging, i found that **my writes into that buffer overlap between invocations** even though I use unique clusterId. I detect it by values of indices[outIndexStart] going over 8 and visual flickering.

According to documentation, gl_GlobalInvocationID is gl_WorkGroupID * gl_WorkGroupSize + gl_LocalInvocationID. But if set all local sizes to 1, write issues go away. Why local_size affects this code in such a way? And how can i reason about choosing it's value here?

```
#version 430
layout (local_size_x = 4, local_size_y = 4, local_size_z = 4) in;

uniform int lightCount;

const unsigned int clusterSize = 32;
const unsigned int clusterSquared = clusterSize * clusterSize;

struct LightInfo {
    vec4 color;
    vec3 position;
    float radius;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer occupancyGrid {
    int exists[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer lightInfos
{
  LightInfo lights [];
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer outputList {
    int indices[];
};

void main(){
    unsigned int clusterId = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x + gl_GlobalInvocationID.y * clusterSize + gl_GlobalInvocationID.z * clusterSquared;

    if(exists[clusterId] == 0)
        return;

    //... not so relevant calculations

    unsigned int outIndexStart = clusterId * 9;
    unsigned int outOffset = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < lightCount && outOffset < 9; i++){
        if(distance(lights[i].position, wordSpace.xyz) < lights[i].radius) {
            indices[outIndexStart + outOffset] = i;
            indices[outIndexStart]++;
            outOffset++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at two declarations:

```
layout (local_size_x = 4, local_size_y = 4, local_size_z = 4) in;
```

and

```
const unsigned int clusterSize = 32;
```

These say *different* things. The `local_size` declaration says that each work group will have 4x4x4 invocations, which is 64. By contrast, your `clusterSize` says that each work group will only have 32 invocations.

If you want to fix this problem, use the [actual local size constant provided by the system](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Inputs):

```
const unsigned int clusterSize = gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.y * gl_WorkGroupSize.z;
```

And you can even do this:

```
const uvec3 linearizeInvocation = uvec3{1, clusterSize, clusterSize * clusterSize};

...

unsigned int clusterId = dot(gl_GlobalInvocationID, linearizeInvocation);
```

Comment: Oh. My shader probably made my intention really confusing. Because instead of thinking that local_size_x\y\z subdivides group into more invocations, i  thought something else nonsensical. One other observation is that my other compute shader doing 3d texture downsampling is faster if i reduce  number of workgroups and increase workgroup size. But it has no shared variables. Is it texture cache or is it more complicated and i must ask another question?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding Nicol, but don't you want clusterSize = 4*4*4 = 64? And won't dot(gl_WorkGroupSize, uvec3(1, 1, 1)) = ((4*1) + (4*1) + (4*1)) = 12? I am still confused by all the different sizes myself, so this may very well be a me issue.

Comment: @Cascades: Fixed.